# Can I use SceneBuilder to edit custom JavaFX controls that inherit from custom JavaFX controls?

Tags: java, user-interface, inheritance, javafx, scenebuilder

I searched the web but infos on this topic are very sparse on the internet.
One example that comes close to my use case [is shown here](http://www.devlabs.ninja/article/fxml-markup-inheritance-javafx), on which I build during this problem demonstration.

I have a custom super control, let's call it `BasicButton`:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
    <children>
        <Button text="Button" onAction="#changeLabel" />
        <Label fx:id="label" text="Basic Button" />
        <HBox fx:id="extension" alignment="CENTER_LEFT"/>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

As you can see, nothing fancy, just a `HBox` with some components.

Then, I have another custom control that extends `BasicButton`, let's call it `SpecialButton`:

```
<fx:root type="basic.BasicButton"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <Label fx:id="anotherLabel" text="Specialized Button"/>
</fx:root>
```

The important part here is the `type="basic.BasicButton"`, i.e., I am "inheriting" from `BasicButton`.

Now my **question**: I can open `BasicButton` without problems in SceneBuilder, but it does not work for `SpecialButton` becaues it says `BasicButton` is not a valid type. This is most probably due to the fact that SceneBuilder does not know about `BasicButton` at all, and only can work with "basic" JavaFX types as `type` (such as `HBox`, ...). Is there a workaround for that?

> java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: basic.BasicButton is not a valid type.
>
> /home/mw/Eclipse/JavaFXPlayground/src/special/SpecialButton.fxml:8
>
> ...

---

---

Just for completeness, the Java controller code:

```
@DefaultProperty("extension")
public class BasicButton extends HBox {

    private @FXML Label label;
    private @FXML HBox extension;

    public BasicButton() {
        URL fxmlFile = BasicButton.class.getResource("BasicButton.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlFile);
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ObservableList<Node> getExtension() {
        return extension.getChildren();
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void changeLabel(ActionEvent event)
    {
        label.setText(label.getText() + "!");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SpecialButton extends BasicButton {
    public SpecialButton() {
        URL fxmlFile = SpecialButton.class.getResource("SpecialButton.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlFile);
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```